# Vite-generated package cannot be consumed by Webpack

Tags: webpack, vite

I have a vite generated npm package.
When I install it and go to `node_modules` I see the following files:

```
myVitePackage/
├─ dist/
│  ├─ index.cjs.js
│  ├─ index.esm.js
├─ package.json
```

File `package.json` defines some dependencies/peer dependencies on Material UI and in particular sets `"type": "module"`.

My project is an empty Webpack CLI project. I just added the dependency upon `myVitePackage` and created a test file to import its React components.

```
// file Test.jsx
import { MyReactComponent } from "myVitePackage"
```

When I run `npm run build` in my project, I see a lot of errors like the one here below. Note that this error is about `@mui/material/styles`, but I find the same also on other libs imported on the index, e.g. `dayjs`.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/myVitePackage/dist/index.esm.js 10:0-46
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@mui/material/styles' in 
'C:\DEV\myProj\node_modules\myVitePackage\dist'
Did you mean 'index.js'?
BREAKING CHANGE: The request '@mui/material/styles' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified
(probably because the origin is strict EcmaScript Module, e. g. a module with javascript mimetype, a '*.mjs' file, or a '*.js' file where the package.json contains '"type": "module"').
The extension in the request is mandatory for it to be fully specified.
Add the extension to the request.
```

Here are the relevant parts of `vite.config.js` of `myVitePackage`.

```
import packages from './package.json';

build: {
    lib: {
      entry: './src/index.tsx',
      formats: ['es'],
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['react', ...Object.keys(packages.peerDependencies)],
      output: {
        preserveModules: true,
      },
    },
    sourcemap: true,
    target: 'es2019',
  },
  plugins: [
    react({
      jsxImportSource: '@emotion/react',
      babel: {
        presets: [['@babel/preset-env', { modules: false }]],
        plugins: [
          '@emotion/babel-plugin',
        ],
      },
    }),
```

I installed ALL the peerDeps and even if Material UI is not on the very same version, they change only for minor or patch numbers.

So my suspect is that there is something wrong in how the `myVitePackage` is boundled by Vite, but I cannot find anything relevant.

## Questions

1. Why Vite produces two index files, `index.esm.js` and `index.cjs.js`? I was expecting `index.js` and `index.cjs`, given that its `package.json` has `"type": "module"`.
2. What does that error actually means and how to fix it?